# Is $0^i$ indeterminate?

Tags: complex-numbers, indeterminate-forms

According to Euler's identity

> **$$e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$$**

Using this identity

> **$$0^i=e^{i\ln{0}}=\cos\ln0+i\sin\ln0=\cos{-\infty}+i\sin{-\infty},\because \ln0=-\infty$$**

But $\cos{-\infty}$ and $\sin{-\infty}$ are indeterminate Does it mean that $0^i$ is indeterminate.
Please Explain.

Comment: $\ln 0$ doesn't exist

Comment: If you want to get into problems *even before* the trigonometric functions, observe that $\;\log 0\;$ is undefined itself...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio $e^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: @Mathstextbook No. $\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^x = 0$. That does not mean that $e^{-\infty} = 0$.

Comment: @arthur $\Lim_{x \to 0}^\ln{x]=-\infty$ You can see the graph

Comment: @Mathstextbook Euler's identity is a theorem about the function $z \to e^{z}$, which is a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Since $\infty$ is not a complex number, the theorem does not apply. You are (implicitly) working with a non-standard definition if you allow expressions like $e^{-\infty}$ to have meaning.

Comment: @Mathstextbook Yes, $\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(x) = -\infty$. I agree. I _do not_ agree, however, that this means that $\ln(0) = -\infty$. Take special care in noting that the "equality" $\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(x) = -\infty$ isn't actually an equality at all. It isn't _actually_ a limit on one side equaling a value on the other. It's just shorthand for "$\ln(x)$ diverges to negative infinity (which isn't a number, by the way) as $x$ approaches $0$"

Comment: It is not “indeterminate”, but rather undefined.

Comment: @egreg is $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate or undefined

Comment: @Mathstextbook Undefined. One speaks about “the indeterminate form $0/0$”, but that's a different matter: it means that we have a limit of a function written as a fraction with numerator and denominator both approaching $0$.

Comment: @Mathstextbook An expression is either defined or undefined, depending on whether there is a deifnition for it or not. A limit of a product, fraction or sum is either determinate or indeterminate depending on whether you can tell what the limit is just from the limits of the two parts. $\frac 00$ is undefined. $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac xx$ is indeterminate.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, I'm voting to close this question   because it really makes no sense. As several comments have pointed out, $\infty$ is just not a number. Y9u are just  playing with formal manipulations. Please use this site for actual mathematical questions you have trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

The critical point comes from the trigonometric functions. Instead, start from the equality
$$
e^{\ln x} = x
$$
which holds for every positive real $x$. Then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x = 0$, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\ln x} = 0$, since $x \to e^x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $-\infty$. Thus in this case, $e^{-\infty} = 0$ is an acceptable convention, which is actually frequently used in mathematics.

However, in your case, neither $\cos x$ nor $\sin x$ have a limit when $x$ tends to $-\infty$. I hope this explains the difference between the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

$Lim_{x \to 0}x^i=Lim_{x \to 0}e^{i\ln x}=Lim_{x \to 0}\cos\ln x+i\sin\ln x$
$\because$ both $\cos{\ln{0}}$ and $\sin{\ln{0}}$ are indeterminate $0^i$ is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're confused because you expect that $0^x=0$ for *any* $x$. This is not true.

$0^x=0$ for any *positive* Real number $x$, but $0^x=\infty$ (or undefined) if $x$ is negative.

More generally, with Complex exponents,

$$b^{x+iy} = \exp\big((x+iy)\ln(b)\big)$$

$$= \exp\big(x\ln(b)+iy\ln(b)\big)$$

$$= \exp\big(x\ln(b)\big)\cdot\exp\big(iy\ln(b)\big)$$

$$= b^x\cdot\big(\cos(y\ln b)+i\sin(y\ln b)\big)$$

If we take a limit as $b\to0$, the left factor $b^x$ has the same behaviour as described above. The right factor (assuming that $y\neq0$) oscillates around the unit circle at increasing speed, because $\ln(b)\to{^-}\infty$.

If $x$ is positive, then $b^x$ damps out the oscillation, and $b^{x+iy}$ converges to $0$.

If $x$ is negative, then $b^x$ amplifies the oscillation, so it diverges.

If $x$ is exactly $0$, then $b^x=1$, and it still diverges (but not to infinity; it just spins around).

So a power of $0$ should be $0$ if the exponent's Real part is positive, $\infty$ (or undefined) if the Real part is negative, and indeterminate (or undefined) if the Real part is $0$.

(Exception: [$0^0=1!$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero))

Answer (score -1):

As you point out, one can not define $0^i$ via the identity of Euler. The question is whether we can find any other good properties of $0^i$. For me good properties would be that the function $f:x\mapsto x^i$ is continuous. This function is basically defined for $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R-}$, where the $log function is not defined.

Can we extend the definition of the function to $0$?
For this we see 
$$\lim_{x\in\mathbb{R},x\rightarrow 0} x^i =$$
$$=\lim_{x\in\mathbb{R},x\rightarrow 0} e^{i\cdot log(x)}$$

This limit does not converge, so we do not have any continuous extension to $0$